# Spark: Getting StackOverflowError inside map function

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark, rdd

Here is my code. Trying to calculate range weight inside map function. Each weight is stored in CountsAsMap.

```
val countsAsMap:Map[Int,Int] = counts.collectAsMap
// countsAsMap: scala.collection.Map[Int,Int] = Map(137 -> 91, 146 -> 83, 218 -> 26, 227 -> 16, ...)
var rangeMatrix = MutableList[(Int, Int)]()
for( i:Int <- min to max;
     j:Int <- min to max) {
    if (i <=j) {
        rangeMatrix += ((i, j))
    }
}
// rangeMatrix : ((301,301), (300,301), (300,300), (299,301), (299,300), ...)
// Creating parallelizable RDD for rangeMatrix
var matrixRDD = sc.parallelize(rangeMatrix)
val rangeWeight = matrixRDD.map(r => {
    var total = 0
    for( k <- r._1 to r._2) {
        total = total + countsAsMap(k)
    }
    total
})
rangeWeight.take(1).foreach(println)
```

Error while running. Have tried multiple ways but all ended up in following exception

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1108)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
```

Note: Instead of RDD if i use collection (List) for transformation (using same map) its working fine.

Comment: Did you try to broadcast the countsAsMap?

Comment: Ya tried broadcasting too

Comment: Where does this happen? (Shell/Program) Have you tried to change this to an immutable Map. You can do that by calling .toMap on it. This is generally a serialization issue...and I believe one that only happens in the shell due to the way it is wrapped.

Comment: I am running this via Zeppelin. Ya will try to run with immutable map

Comment: Ya also tried with immutable map. still getting same error

Comment: could you give detailed error stack include the error positon in your code?

Comment: This code is working fine for me. Can you provide the entire error stack trace , and some info about how large the data is (min , max and the map)

Comment: Ya sure min is 0 and Max is 300-400

Comment: Will get complete stack trace soon

Comment: I've got something similar with training random forest. I believe that was the case, when the tree has to be serialized to the driver or between the workers (unfortunately I didn't figure that out), but running my application with -Dspark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:ThreadStackSize=81920" helped. It's true I specify 80MB for stack thread size and I didn't know how much actually required in my case. You can try to configure Zeppelin to run spark executors with smth less value. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have two questions 1) where can i see the complete logs of my stack trace? Zeppelin truncates after 100 lines or so. And i couldn't find exact logs info  in /var/log/zeppelin/zeppelin-zeppelin-ip-*** FYI i am using AWS EMR. 2) Do I have to recreate my cluster to set -spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-XX:ThreadStackSize=81920" in EMR? Zeppelin interpreter doesn't allow me to add this setting

Comment: ok I tried setting XX:ThreadStackSize to 80MB but still getting same error